# having trouble understanding how to chain objects in the implementation of other classes

Tags: c++

I'm having a compiler error when trying to add each card(suit and rank) into the object's Card.

Here is the `Card.h` file:

```
#define CARD_H
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Card{

    private:
        int rank;
        int suit;
        
    public:
    // must have constructors, destructor, accessor methods, and mutator methods
    Card();
    Card(int, int);
    ~Card();
    
    int get_rank();
    int get_suit();
    
    void set_rank(int);
    void set_suit(int);
    string fillrank(int) ;
    string fillsuit(int) ;
    void printcards();
    /*
    string getr_ank();
    string gets_uit();
    void setr_ank(string);
    void sets_uit(string);
    */

};

#endif
```

`Card.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include "card.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

Card::Card(){

    rank = 0;
    suit = 0;

}

Card::Card(int r, int s){

    rank = r;
    suit = s;
    //cout << "Parameterized constructor" << endl;

}

int Card::get_rank(){

    return rank;

}

int Card::get_suit(){

    return suit;

}

void Card::set_rank(int rank){

    this->rank = rank;

}

void Card::set_suit(int suit){

    this->suit = suit;

}

string Card::fillrank(int rank) {

switch(rank){
        case 0:
            return "Ace";
                break;
        case 1:
            return "2";
                break;
        case 2:
            return "3";
                break;
        case 3:
            return "4";
                break;
        case 4:
            return "5";
                break;
        case 5:
            return "6";
                break;
        case 6:
            return "7";
                break;
        case 7:
            return "8";
                break;
        case 8:
            return "9";
                break;
        case 9:
            return "10";
                break;
        case 10:
            return "Jack (J)";
                break;
        case 11:
            return "Queen (Q)";
                break;
        case 12:
            return "King (K)";
                break;
    }

}

string Card::fillsuit(int suit) {

    switch(suit){

        case 0:
            return "Clubs";
                break;
        case 1:
            return "Spades";
                break;
        case 2:
            return "Hearts";
                break;
        case 3:
            return "Diamonds";
                break;

    }
}

void Card::printcards(){

cout << rank << " of " << suit << endl;

}

Card::~Card(){
 cout << "Destructor called!" << endl;
```

`deck.h`

```
#ifndef DECK_H
#define DECK_H
#include "card.h"

class Deck{
    private:
        Card cards[52];
        int n_cards; //Number of cards remaining in the deck.
    public:
        //must have constructors, destructor, accessor methods, and mutator methods.

    Deck();
    

    int get_cards();

    void set_cards(int);
    void filldeck();
    void printdeck();
    ~Deck();


};

#endif
```

`deck.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include "deck.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

Deck::Deck(){

    n_cards = 0;

}

int Deck::get_cards(){

    return n_cards;
}

void Deck::set_cards(int cards){

    n_cards = cards;

}

void Deck::filldeck(){

    int a = 0;
    Card p1;
    for (int x = 0; x <13 ;x++){
        for(int y = 0; y < 4; y++){
            cards[a] = p1.fillrank(x);
            cards[a] =  p1.fillsuit(y) ;

            a++;
        }
    }

}

void Deck::printdeck(){

    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++){
        cards[i].printcards();
    }

}

Deck::~Deck(){


}
```

`This is the error I'm getting:`

```
deck.cpp:52:22: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘Card’ and ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}’)
             cards[a] = p1.fillrank(x);
ard.h:7:7: note: Card& Card::operator=(const Card&)
 class Card{
       ^
card.h:7:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘const Card&’
deck.cpp:53:22: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘Card’ and ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}’)
             cards[a] =  p1.fillsuit(y) ;
```

Why can't I fill each rank and suit into the Card object? what I'm missing here? how should I approach this? Thank you beforehand.

Comment: Pop quiz: what does your `fillrank()` method return? What values are stored in the `card[]` array? Can you assign one to the other (the answer is no, of course, that's what your C++ compiler is telling you, but answering the first two questions will point you to the reason why).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens here is that your `fillrank` and `fillsuit` doesn't actually fill the rank and suit of that card, instead it returns the rank and suit it should be filled with.

To actually make the fill the rank, you need to do something like `rank = "Ace"` in that function.

So you would change your function to something like:

```
void fillrank(int rank)
{
    switch(rank)
    {
        case 0:
            this.rank = "Ace";
            break;
        case 1:
            this.rank = "2";
            break;
        case 2:
            .
            .
            .
    }
}
```

And in your `filldeck` function, you could just call each card from the deck, and apply `fillrank` on them directly, like:

```
cards[a].fillrank(x);
```

Comment: That makes sense.  I appreciate the help!